# .htaccess remove trailing slash after file extension

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some external links to my site that referrer to pages with a file extension and a trailing slash after that e.g.

http://example.com/folder/page.php/

I can not change these links, but I would like to 301 redirect those links to this format instead:

http://example.com/folder/page/

I've tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php\/$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your /.htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php/? [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Its works! Thanks alot for your help. Care to explain why i works? Are there two separate rewrites in this solution, and is this a 301 redirect?

Comment: Keat, rule in your question doesn't work because ,it redirects "foo.php" to /foo, "/foo" doesn't exist on the server, so it returns a 404 error. My rules redirect "/foo.php" to "/foo" and then it mapps "/foo" back to "/foo.php".

Comment: Keat, it's 302 Temp redirect, To make it permanent ,change **R** to **R=301** ,eg : [NC,R=301,L]

Comment: Perfect, works lika a charm. And thanks for the explanation. Do i need to change the last line to a R=301 as well?

Comment: No, don't change the last line. its not for external redirection. it's for mapping "file" to "file.php" , (internal Redirect)

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it very much. Have a nice day.

Comment: the code works perfect, except for one thing. if I type in a url to a page that doesn't exist, I get a "Internal Server Error". If I remove your code, I get the regular 404 (the only other line of code in the .htaccess is this: `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` ). Any idea how to fix this?