# Slash after file extension can not be redirected

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am using these htaccess code to remove and redirect php extension to without file extension.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Then I try to use another slightly different code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Both code produce same problem, if try to access

1. domain.com/other/content.php goes to domain.com/other/content (200 response)

Now here is strange behaviour, if try to access

2. domain.com/other/content.php/ goes to domain.com/other/content.php/ (200 response not 404)
3. domain.com/other/content.php/any-word goes to domain.com/other/content.php/any-word (200 response not 404 error)

All other redirect work perfectly, besides this problem.
Can any one help with both code, I need both code rectification, as I have two different site with both htaccess rule.

Comment: I write an answer below, which I found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31460693/htaccess-remove-trailing-slash-after-file-extension If I add this with above code, it working, but I keep this code alone, it not working. Can any one explain why and using both code can make complications ? Please see my answer

Answer (score 0):

If I keep both code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Plus, I add new code then it works

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php/? [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: Does this make new complications ?